# Python: copy of a variable

Tags: python, variables, copy

Is there a way in to make copy of a variable so that when the value changes of variable 'a' it copies itself to variable 'b'?

Example

```
a='hello'

b=a     #.copy()  or a function that will make a copy

a='bye'

# Is there a way to make 
# 'b' equal 'a' without 
# doing 'b=a'

print a
print b
```

I am having a problem using the Tkinter library where I have checkbutton that has been stored in a list and I'm trying to get the variable that it holds.

But it takes around **5 lines of code** to reach the variable.

#### Is there a way of holding a copy of the variable that changes when the checkbutton variable changes?

Comment: Why would you want that? just use `a`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating Pointers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python)

Comment: See [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986006)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're exploring how Python deals with references. Assignment is simply binding a reference to an object on the right hand side. So, this is somewhat trivial:

```
a = 'foo'
b = a
print b is a  #True -- They *are the same object*
```

However, as soon as you do:

```
b = 'bar'
b is a  #False -- they're not longer the same object because you assigned a new object to b
```

Now this becomes really interesting with objects which are *mutable*:

```
a = [1]
b = a
b[0] = 'foo'
print a  #What?? 'a' changed?
```

In this case, `a` changes because `b` and `a` are referencing the same object. When we make a change to `b` (which we can do since it is mutable), that same change is seen at `a` because they're the same object.

So, to answer your question, you can't do it directly, but you can do it indirectly if you used a mutable type (like a list) to store the actual data that you're carrying around.

---

This is something that is very important to understand when working with Python code, and it's not the way a lot of languages work, so it pays to really think about/research this until you truly understand it.

Comment: I came here to find a way to prevent the behavior in the third scenario (object to be copied is mutable). In case others wanted the same info, what I eventually found is that other than using copy.copy or copy.deepcopy, you may also use the following syntax to create a new object and negate the mutability of the original -- if the desired object can be instantiated in such a way of course:
```new_list = list(L) # copy
new_dict = dict(olddict) # copy

new_set = set(L) # convert list to set
new_tuple = tuple(L) # convert list to tuple```

Answer (score 2):

In short, with simple value assignments, you cannot do this.  As you saw:

```
a=4
b=a
a=5

>>> print b
4
```

However, with mutable objects like lists, you *can* do this.  As such:

```
a=[1]
b=a
a.append(2)

>>> print a
[1,2]
>>> print b
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to check the [weakref module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html).

This allows you to have a primary object and then several copies that will become `None` as soon as the primary object is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if it is possible to create a reference to a variable and hold in another variable.  No, this is not possible.  See e.g. [Create a reference to a variable (similar to PHP's "=&")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301805/create-a-reference-to-a-variable-similar-to-phps)

Answer (score -1):

There is an ugly way to create an independent copy of a simple variable via a temporary list:

```
a = 6; 
b = [a][0]
```

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but this code doesn't work for making a copy of a simple variable (even in Python 2)