# Tensorflow: tf.random_normal get different results with the same initial seed

Tags: tensorflow, random, initializer

I want to make a reusable `RANDOM TENSOR x` and assign the SAME tensor to  `VARIABLE y`. That means they should have the same value during `Session.run()`.

But it turns out not the case. So why does `y` NOT equal `x`?

Update:
After applying `sess.run(x)` and `sess.run(y)` multiple times in line, confirmed that `x` changes every time while `y` stays steady. Why?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_normal([3], seed = 1)
y = tf.Variable(initial_value = x) # expect y get the same random tensor as x

diff = tf.subtract(x, y)
avg = tf.reduce_mean(diff)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(y.initializer)

print('x0:', sess.run(x))
print('y0:', sess.run(y))
print('x1:', sess.run(x))
print('y1:', sess.run(y))
print('x2:', sess.run(x))
print('y2:', sess.run(y))
print('diff:', sess.run(diff))
print('avg:', sess.run(avg)) # expected as 0.0

sess.close()
```

Ouputs: TENSOR x changes every sess.run(x)

```
x0: [ 0.55171245 -0.13107552 -0.04481386]
y0: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
x1: [-0.67590594  0.28665832  0.3215887 ]
y1: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
x2: [1.2409041  0.44875884 0.33140722]
y2: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
diff: [ 1.2404865  -1.4525002   0.05412297]
avg: -0.04116
```

Comment: Please try `sess.run(tf.global_variable_initilizer())` instead of your initialization. Does this help? And maybe set the length of your tensor to 2 so that you can visually compare both.

Comment: @Lau sess.run(tf.global_variable_initilizer()) is the same as sess.run(y.initializer). And apply sess.run(tf.equal(x, y)) you will get a tensor with all False. Have a try.

Comment: Ok, sry. I tested some code now. `tf.random_normal` draws a normal distribution at every call. This is meant to be, because you want sometime generate noise. If your variables to be static use: `tf.get_variable("test", shape=[3], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true cause is that:
`x = tf.random_normal(seed = initial_seed)`is evolving every time when applying `sess.run()` but produces the same tensor series `x0-x1-x2` if **restart** running the script. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do) provides some explanation on **random seed**.

To guarantee the same `x` after every first run, we need **reinitialize** it. Not sure there is a decent way for my case. But we can set `x` as a variable and initialize with a fixed seed. Either `tf.get_variable` or `tf.Variable` is OK. I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888235/how-do-i-generate-a-random-vector-in-tensorflow-and-maintain-it-for-further-use/34888586#34888586) fit my question.

Here is my final code. It works.

```
import tensorflow as tf

initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(seed = 1)
x = tf.get_variable(name = 'x', shape = [3], dtype = tf.float32, initializer = initializer)
y = tf.Variable(initial_value = x)

diff = tf.subtract(x, y)
avg = tf.reduce_mean(diff)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print('x0:', sess.run(x))
print('y0:', sess.run(y))

print('x1:', sess.run(x))
print('y1:', sess.run(y))

print('x2:', sess.run(x))
print('y2:', sess.run(y))

print('diff:', sess.run(diff))
print('avg:', sess.run(avg))
sess.close()

x0: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
y0: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
x1: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
y1: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
x2: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
y2: [-0.8113182   1.4845988   0.06532937]
diff: [0. 0. 0.]
avg: 0.0
```