# Why is variable changing despite only being assigned once per loop?

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple version of Conway's Game of Life. When I input something such as 0001, the output should be 1010. The program handles the 1's and 0's as bools.

In the code snippet below, I'm printing the 'copy' variable, which should only change once per generation. Instead, it's changing every time the for loop loops. Why is 'copy' changing? Shouldn't 'state' be the only thing that's changing?

```
def adj(state,i):
    a = b = False
    if i == 0: #checking on left wall
        a = state[-1]
        b = state[i+1]
    elif i == len(state)-1: #checking on right wall
        a = state[i-1]
        b = state[0]
    else: #checking in the middle
        a = state[i-1]
        b = state[i+1]
    return [a,b].count(True)

def evolve(state):
    copy = state #changes are made to state based on the copy
    for i in range(len(copy)):
        print(copy)
        if adj(copy,i) == 1:
            state[i] = True
        else:
            state[i] = False
    return state
```

Comment: you set copy = state, so that means both variables point to the same value. Maybe what you want is copy = copy.copy(state)

Comment: Read this for a better understanding of *why* `copy = state` does not make a copy. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: You can also read the accepted answer on this SO question about trying to do the inverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538266/python-copy-of-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code:

```
copy = state
```

does **not** make a separate copy of 'state'.  'copy' and 'state' now refer to the SAME list object.

If you want a separate copy, use slicing instead:

```
copy = state[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

`copy` and `state` are both names for the same object.
That object (probably a list) happens to have a `__setitem__` method, through which you mutate it.

Demo:

```
>>> state = [1,2,3]
>>> copy = state
>>> state[2] = 42
>>> copy
[1, 2, 42]
>>> state
[1, 2, 42]
```

If you want your `copy` to actually be a name for a copy of `state`, you need a copy of `state`.

```
>>> state = [1,2,3]
>>> copy = state[:] # make a shallow copy of state
>>> state[2] = 42
>>> copy
[1, 2, 3]
>>> state
[1, 2, 42]
```