# Python reassign value instead of variable

Tags: python

Is it possible to reassign the value referenced to by a variable, rather than the variable itself?

```
a = {"example": "foo"}
b = a
```

When I reassign `a`, it is reassigning the variable a to reference a new value. Therefore, `b` does not point to the new value.

```
a = {"example": "bar"}
print(b["example"]) # -> "foo"
```

How do I instead reassign the value referenced by a? Something like:

```
*a = {"example": "bar"}
print(b["example"]) # -> "bar"
```

I can understand if this isn't possible, as Python would need a double pointer under the hood.

---

**EDIT** Most importantly, I need this for reassigning an object value, similar to JavaScript's [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function. I assume Python will have double pointers for objects. I can wrap other values in an object if necessary.

Comment: you will find this useful: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: @Sayse Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: @Sayse That's not a distinction that exists in Python.  All Python values are objects.

Comment: You could use a box type or a container (e.g. list) to hold an indirect reference.

Comment: Alternatively, you could lookup the variable in the `locals()` dict, though that's kind of strange.

Comment: for a dictionary, just clear it, and update it with new data: you keep the old reference. For a list, use `a[:] = ...` to keep the old reference.

Comment: What's the use case? Why would you want that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538266/python-copy-of-a-variable) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: Was this a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), in the end?

Comment: @Sayse python had no distinction between value types and reference types. Everything acts like a reference type, everything is an object. And mutability isn't relevant here, really, both immutable and mutable types behave the exact same way as far as assignment works

Answer (score 2):

Python variables simply do not operate this way, and simple assignment won't do what you want. Instead, you can clear the existing dict and update it in-place.

```
>>> a = dict(example="foo")
>>> b = a
>>> a.clear()
>>> a
{}
>>> a.update({'example': 'bar'})
>>> b
{'example': 'bar'}
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks! `update` is the method I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 2 dictionaries, so that's 2 different objects in memory. If you don't want that, keep 1 dictionary only.

```
a = {"example": "foo"}
b = a
a["example"] = "bar"
print(b["example"])
```

Comment: However, I am given another dict from another function, and need to transfer that into my existing dictionary. `update` is what I was looking for in @chepner's answer